# A word for being trasferred from one customer rep to another?

Tags: single-word-requests

Have you had a simple request but because you were talking to a call center, the simple request turned out into a big chain of transfers to all kinds of different departments and all kinds of specialists because the person you talked to either didn't have the authority or the expertise to help you from start to finish?

Example Sentence: When I called for tech support I got trapped inside a _____________

Is there a word for this?

Comment: If you want to be literary, you got caught [up] in a [***Kafkaesque**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Kafkaesque) nightmare*. In more colloquial terms, you were sent / transferred / redirected [***from pillar to post**.*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/from-pillar-to-post)

Comment: A Google search for "phone transfer hell" turns up 23 unique matches.

Comment: "Phone maze" is super common, but it usually refers specifically to *automated* phone transferring ("push 1 for billing..." etc.) rather than a situation where you can actually talk to real people, but they're the wrong real people to help you.

Comment: You were sucked down an average corporate customer-support rabbit hole. Happens all the time, sometimes seemingly by design.

Comment: But +1 - we need a few new and hearty words for this particular hell.

Comment: a term used here is "I was *handed-off* to some other fool..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were (inside of/ being given/ getting) the [runaround](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/runaround):

> To receive unclear, misleading, incomplete, or evasive information, especially in a response to a question or request. *I always get the runaround when I call the telephone company to explain all these extra charges. The reporter tried to get a clear answer from the senator regarding her stance on immigration, but he just got the runaround.*

I note that one of TFD's example sentences very closely parallels your own, regarding a call center.

I would slightly re-arrange that however, and phrase it as:

> When I called for tech support I was given the runaround.

Comment: also "handed-off" or simply "passed" or "passed on to" ...

Answer (score 1):

***shunted***

> When I called for tech support, I got ***shunted** to different reps continuously*.

From [**collinsdictionary.com**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shunt):

> Collins English Dictionary
>
> **shunt**
> *verb*
>
> **4.** (transitive) to evade by putting off onto someone else
>
> COBUILD Advanced British English Dictionary
>
> **1.** *verb* [usu passive] If a person or thing is shunted somewhere, they are moved or sent there, usually because someone finds them
> inconvenient. [disapproval] '
>
> He has spent most of
> his life being shunted between his mother, father and various foster
> families.
>
> Independent thinkers are shunted into
> minor jobs or refused promotion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an English equivalent for a word or expression in another language that refers specifically to the situation you describe in your question, then one option would be to paraphrase.

So not "I got trapped inside XYZ" but maybe "I was endlessly redirected back and forth" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Example Sentence: When I called for tech support I got trapped inside (in) a ________

**(Call center) Relay.**

> *Source: Merriam Webster*
>
> : the act
>   of passing something from one person or device to another ; also : a system for doing
>   this